# Optimized way to check and update many variables at once if the condition is the same - PYTHON

Tags: python, optimization

i'm beginner in Python and i'm trying to do a game. This part of the code works fine as it is, but i'm pretty sure that there's a more elegant way to do the same thing.

Basically if a variable reaches above 100, the value will be 100. If the value is lower than 0, the value will be 0. (like a limit)

```
if economy >= 100:
    economy = 100
if economy <= 0:
    economy = 0
if population >= 100:
    population = 100
if population <= 0:
    population = 0
if religion >= 100:
    religion = 100
if religion <0:
    religion = 0
```

As I said, the code works, but I'm pretty sure that there's a optimized way to do this since the condition is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if economy >= 100:
>     economy = 100
> if economy <= 0:
>     economy = 0
> if population >= 100:
>     population = 100
> if population <= 0:
>     population = 0
> if religion >= 100:
>     religion = 100
> if religion <0:
>     religion = 0
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
economy = max(0, min(100, economy))
population = max(0, min(100, population))
religion  = max(0, min(100, religion))
```

First you take the minimum of 100 and `x`. If `x >= 100`, then you get 100, otherwise you get `x`.

Suppose `y = min(100, x)`. Then you take the maximum of `y` and 0. If `y <= 0`, you get 0. Otherwise, you get `y`.

You could make this even more concise by generalizing the code. For example, could you hold all of the values you're counting in a list or dictionary? Then you could do something like this:

```
for i in range(counts):
    counts[i] = max(0, min(100, counts[i])
```

or

```
ECONOMY_KEY = "ECONOMY"
POPULATION_KEY = "POPULATION"
RELIGION_KEY = "RELIGION"

keys = [ECONOMY_KEY, POPULATION_KEY, RELIGION_KEY]

...

for key in keys:
    counts[key] = max(0, min(100, counts[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly open-ended question, you could look into one-line if statements as a possibility, and somewhere within your entire program, make sure that the values can not go below 0. That would look something like

```py
company = 100 if company >= 100 else company
economy = 100 if economy >= 100 else economy
```

However, this does not necessarily solve your problem much. Uploading your entire program may prove to be useful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will not upload the entire program because it will more than 200 lines and I only need this specific part that updates by the player click. But this solution is interesting.